# php forum login throwing error

Tags: php, html

Ive tried my best to try and fix this multiple time but something is still wrong with the code and I keep getting errors coming from the php

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/a9114464/public_html/api/api.php on line 10
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/a9114464/public_html/api/api.php on line 12
```

Now here is the api.php file

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLE");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

function login($username, $password){
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($check_user>0){

$_SESSION[‘username’]=$username;

}

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in /home/a9114464/public_html/api/api.php on line 10

--> `$conn` is defined and assigned outside function. Use `global` to get use `$conn` in the function scope.

```
function login($username, $password){
 global $scope;
```

OR, pass `$conn` as third parameter to `login`. And call `login()` with three parameters.

```
function login($username, $password, $conn) {
```

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /home/a9114464/public_html/api/api.php on line 12

--> When first problem fixed, this will also be fixed.

Comment: So I added global $conn; but now I have error on 13 Saying mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/a9114464/public_html/api/api.php on line 13

Comment: @JacobWebb, print the query and run it in your MySQL client like phpmyadmin, Dbeaver.

Comment: Something is still wrong the website address is http://hobolandjacob.hostoi.com/test.php

Comment: The username and password are test : test

Comment: Please read all errors over there. They are too simple to fix.

Comment: Thanks got it working

Answer (score 0):

Pass the $con object to the function

```
function login($username, $password,$conn){
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($check_user>0){

$_SESSION[‘username’]=$username;

}

}
```